# Animate Frame Size in Cocoa plus notification on animation end

Tags: cocoa, caanimation

At the moment i have this code:

```
[[myView animator] setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(300, 150)];
```

And at the end of the animation i need to launch other operations so i need to know about that.

On the otherside i read the the CAAnimation class has a delegate method that could be exactly what i'm looking for (animationDidStop:finished:), but i like to know it i can have the same effect using animator proxy o CABasicAnimation.